# Unable to call async and parallel method inside my asp.net console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task

I have an asp.net console application, and inside this console application I want to call an async method in a parallel manner using `WhenAll`, here is my console application main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Marketing ipfd = new Marketing();
    try
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the PM API to get the account id
        {
            //code goes here...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    var tasks = ipfd.companies.Select(c => gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);}
}
```

And here is the method i am calling :-

```
class Program
{
    static int concurrentrequests = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConcurrentRequests"]);
    SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: concurrentrequests);
    int numberofrequests = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberofrequests"].ToString());
    int waitduration = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["waitdurationmilsc"].ToString());

    private async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string website)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        ScanInfo si = new ScanInfo();
        var tasks = ipfd.companies.Select(c =>   gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.website.value)).ToList();
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But i am getting these exceptions:-

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property '***.Program.gettingCustomerInfo(string)'

So can anyone advice on this? Now I know the first exception is regarding that the Main method itself is not async, but if I define the main method to be async then i will get another exception that the program does not contain a Main method that can be called as end point ?

Comment: You tried Task mainTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait() ?

Comment: @LeBigCat now if i define the following `var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();` i will get this error `Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable *****\Program.cs` + i will still get my above second error..

Comment: Yeah if your tasks doesnot return void, you have to add the type to the mainTask also (this is the first answer bellow ;))

Comment: @LeBigCat not sure what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Task<desiredType> or var mainTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait() works too, you could also use Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get around this

**Preferred option**

Use the newly available `async Main` support which is available as of C# 7.1 by taking the following steps:

- Edit your project file to use C# 7.1 (Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Select C#7.1 as your language version)
- Change your Main method to the following:

`static async Task Main(string[] args) { ... }`

Here is an example project demonstrating a working version:

https://github.com/steveland83/AsyncMainConsoleExample

In case it is of interest, here's an informal set of excercises I wrote up to demonstrate a few ways to handle async tasks (and some common basic mistakes): https://github.com/steveland83/async-lab

**Option 2**

If, for whatever reason you are unable to use the approach above, you can force the async code to run synchronously (be warned, this is almost always considered bad practice).

```
var aggregateTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
aggregateTask.Wait();
```

Comment: @Steve Land now i installed VS 2017, and i changed my code to use c# 7.1.then i changed my method to be `static async Task Main(string[] args) { ... }`. but now i am getting 2 errors 1) `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point` 2) `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.gettingCustomerInfo(string)'` .. so not sure what is causing these errors?

Comment: @testtest I've added links to some complete working examples. Please compare these to what you have - if you still have errors please open a new question to address those specifically. Good luck :)